# In Products review, how do I set a hyperlink to a certain word? e.g. Click Here

Tags: product, review

How do I set a hyperlink to a customer's review for individual products to link to a external URL?
e.g. Click here to read more.
I want to add a hyperlink to "here".

Comment: can you give more information what exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying something like you want to set anchor link to some text. So, for that you can add below code in your phtml file in which you want to add link.

`<a href="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl()">Click Here</a>`